# Linear Programming: Add penalty as variable diverge from optimal value, with single value exception

Tags: linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to have a penalty constraint in my LP project, the solver is looking for an optimal value of x (integer value), among other constraints, I want x to be penalized the more it diverges from an optimal value.

I added this constraint as

```
self.prob += x - optimal_size <= _SP
self.prob += x - optimal_size >= -_SP
```

Adding _SP as penalty to my objective function

```
objective += other_values - 0.1 * SP
```

In this case, optimal_size is == 3, but I'd also like however that this penalty would not be applied if x == 0. Do you have a suggestion on what would be a nice way to do it?

Comment: So when you are trying to find the optimal value of `x`, is the value from which you want to measure the divergence from (and penalise) fixed ? Like in the above example you say, `optimal_size is == 3` is `3` known beforehand.

Comment: Yes, it is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is as follows :

1. calculate the divergence of `x` from `optimal_x_fixed` in variable : `divergence_x_from_fixed_raw`
2. take the absolute of the above divergence in variable : `divergence_x_from_fixed_absolute`
3. create a boolean variable : `impose_penalty_bool` to highlight that: 
   if `x == 0` => `impose_penalty_bool == 0` 
   if `x >= 1` => `impose_penalty_bool == 1`
4. create an integer variable `final_penalty_value` to store the multiplication of `impose_penalty_bool` and `divergence_x_from_fixed_absolute`
5. effect from 4) will be 
   if `x == 0` => `impose_penalty_bool == 0` => `final_penalty_value == 0` 
   if `x == optimal_x_fixed` => `impose_penalty_bool == 1` => `final_penalty_value == 0` (beacuse absolute of deviance == 0) 
   if `x != 0` and `absolute of deviance > 0` => `impose_penalty_bool = 1` => `final_penalty_value > 0`

I have used Google-ortool's linear solver, but below implementation can be used with any other linear solver:

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

solver = pywraplp.Solver("penalty_obj",pywraplp.Solver.SCIP_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

# below value is fixed for a given iteration, but can be changed in subsequent run
optimal_x_fixed = 3

# decision variable
x = solver.IntVar(lb = -10, ub = 10, name = "x")

# since we (I) dont know the objective function, in order to test the logic,
# I have fixed the value of x
x.SetBounds(lb = 3, ub = 3)

# The absolute value is a non-linear function. We will have to linearise it

# ------------------- STEPS 1 and 2, START ----------------------#
# here we calculate the divergence between "x" and the "optimal_x_fixed"
divergence_x_from_fixed_raw = solver.IntVar(lb = -20, ub = 20, name = "divergence_raw")
solver.Add(divergence_x_from_fixed_raw == optimal_x_fixed - x)

# create a variable which will store the absolute value of the divergence
divergence_x_from_fixed_absolute = solver.IntVar(lb = 0, ub = 20, name = "divergence_abs")

# create a positive and negative part
# idea is only one of the parts can have a value other than zero at any time
divergence_x_from_fixed_pos = solver.IntVar(lb = 0, ub = 20, name = "divergence_pos")
divergence_x_from_fixed_neg = solver.IntVar(lb = 0, ub = 20, name = "divergence_neg")
divergence_x_binary = solver.BoolVar("")

solver.Add(divergence_x_from_fixed_raw == divergence_x_from_fixed_pos - divergence_x_from_fixed_neg)

# below constraint ensure that only positive or negative part takes value other than zero
# 100 is big_M
solver.Add(divergence_x_from_fixed_pos <= 100 * divergence_x_binary)
solver.Add(divergence_x_from_fixed_neg <= 100 * (1 - divergence_x_binary))

solver.Add(divergence_x_from_fixed_absolute == divergence_x_from_fixed_pos + divergence_x_from_fixed_neg)

# ------------------- STEPS 1 and 2, END ----------------------#

# ------------------- STEPS 3, START ----------------------#

# next we want to create a boolean variable : "impose_penalty_bool"
# what we want is if x == 0, then impose_penalty_bool == 0
#                 if x >= 1, then mpose_penalty_bool == 1
# however, if x == 3, then also we dont want any penalty,
# this will tackle next

impose_penalty_bool = solver.BoolVar("")

# 100 is upper bound on x
# below 2 constraints achieve: 
    # if x == 0, then impose_penalty_bool == 0:
    # if x >= 1, then mpose_penalty_bool == 1        
solver.Add(x - (100 * impose_penalty_bool) <= 0)
solver.Add(x - impose_penalty_bool >= 0)

# ------------------- STEPS 3, END ----------------------#

# ------------------- STEPS 4, START ----------------------#

# finally what we want to do is multiply "impose_penalty_bool"
# with the absolute of deviance from "optimal_x_fixed = 3" we calculated earlier
# the effect will be:
    
    # if x == 0 => impose_penalty_bool == 0 => final_penalty_value == 0
    # if x == optimal_x_fixed => impose_penalty_bool = 1 => final_penalty_value == 0
      # (beacuse absolute of deviance == 0)
    # if x != 0 and absolute of deviance > 0 => impose_penalty_bool = 1 => final_penalty_value > 0
    

# multiply impose_penalty_bool with divergence_x_from_fixed_absolute
final_penalty_value = solver.IntVar(lb = 0, ub = 20, name = "final_penalty")
# u is the upper bound on divergence_x_from_fixed_absolute. u = 30 (say)
solver.Add(final_penalty_value <= 30 * impose_penalty_bool)
solver.Add(final_penalty_value <= divergence_x_from_fixed_absolute)
solver.Add(final_penalty_value >= divergence_x_from_fixed_absolute - 30 * (1 - impose_penalty_bool))

# by doing above we linearise the product of binary : impose_penalty_bool # and the integer variable : divergence_x_from_fixed_absolute

# generally, if x1 is binary, and x2 is continuous / integer
# u is upper bound on x2. introduce a y variable to hold the product
# impose following constraints
# y <= u * x1
# y <= x2
# y <= x2 - u * (1 - x1)
# y >= 0


# ------------------- STEPS 4, END ----------------------#

# DEFINE OBJECTIVE FUNCTION #

obj_function = x + final_penalty_value

solver.Maximize(obj_function) # or minimise, depends
solver.Solve()

solver.Objective().Value()

# ----------------------------------- #
```

I have checked with different values of `x`, outcome is on expected lines.
final_penalty_value == 0 if x == 0 or x == 3 (equal to fixed value)
for x != 3 or x != 0, final_penalty_value > 0

Comment: This is quite complex, but I guess my problem was not too easy to formulate.
Thanks for the answer!